# Improving the second table to be as correct as the first one

Tags: horizontal-alignment, multicolumn, multirow

Could you please help me in making the second table correct and without errors (similarly to the first one), Also, in removing the first column (Roadmap) from both

First table:

```
\documentclass{article}
            \pagestyle{empty}
            \usepackage[paperheight=11in,paperwidth=7in, margin=0.5in,landscape]{geometry}
            \usepackage{tikz}
            \usepackage{array}
            \usepackage{makecell}
            \usepackage{color, colortbl}
            \usepackage{multirow}
            \usepackage{hhline}
            \usetikzlibrary{calc}

            \begin{document}
                    \begin{table}[]
                    \centering
                    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
                        \hline
                        \multirow{25.66}{*}{Roadmap} & \multirow{7.5}{*}{February} & \multirow{-2}{*}{Week1} &\makecell[l]{Installing the simulation environment \\ Adding the UR manipulator to the simulation environment \\ Getting familiar with the simulation environment(learning how to include and position simple objects cube, ball, etc.)}\\[-3ex] \cline{3-3}
                         & & Week2 \\ \cline{3-4}
                          & & Week3 & \makecell[l]{ Literature studies on grasping a cube and navigating between two waypoints\\ Documentation} \\ \cline{3-4}
                          & & \multirow{-2}{*}{Week4} & \makecell[l]{Literature studies on grasping a cube and navigating between (set of) waypoints\\ Coding the navigation towards the position of the object\\ Coding the grasp to the object\\ Coding the navigation of the grasped object from it's initial position towards pre-defined target waypoint\\ Documentation} \\[-3ex] \cline{2-3}
                          & \multirow{10}{*}{March} & Week1 & \\ \cline{3-4}
                          & & \multirow{-2}{*}{Week2}& \makecell[l]{ Literature studies on the cable implementation (reduced stiffness objects)\\ Implementing and Positioning the cable at a certain position in the workspace\\ Documentation} \\[-3ex]
                          \cline{3-3}
                           & & Week3 \\
                          \cline{3-4}
                          & & \multirow{-2}{*}{Week4} & \makecell[l]{Coding the grasp to the cable and conducting the navigation from the initial to goal waypoint\\ Confirming the no drop of the cable during the navigation\\ Documentation \\---\\ \textit{Note: The items in this field are started to be applied in a fixed manner (No machine learning model to be developed). }\\ \textit{In case the fixed manner isn't giving sufficient results, an RL model to be developed, the task to be extended more three weeks} \\\textit{and the shortest path planning task to be eliminated}} \\[-2.75ex] \cline{2-3}
                          & \multirow{5.5}{*}{April} & Week1 & \\ \cline{3-4}
                          & & Week2 & \makecell[l]{Literature studies on reinforcement learning\\ (Deep deterministic policy gradient and Deep Q-learning)\\ Documentation} \\[-2.8ex] \cline{3-3}
                          & & Week3 & \\ \cline{3-4}
                          & & \multirow{-2}{*}{Week4} & \makecell[l]{Developing a Reinforcement learning model to navigate the grasped cable to the predefined target waypoint\\ Documentation \\
                          ---\\ \textit{Note: For the grasping task, the code developed in the March's 4th week will be} used} \\[-2.8ex] \cline{2-3}
                          & May & Week1 & \\ \hline
                    \end{tabular}
                    \end{table}
```

Second table:

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multirow{Roadmap} & \multirow{May}    & Week2 & \multirow{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Inserting certain fixed object(s) to be considered as obstacle(s)\\ Reconstructing the reinforcement learning model\\ Retraining the reinforcement learning model\\ Documentation\end{tabular}} \\ \cline{3-3}
                          &                         & Week3 &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            \\ \cline{3-4} 
                          &                         & Week4 & \multirow{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Transforming the obstacles from fixed to dynamic\\ Reconstructing/Extending the reinforcement learning model\\ Retraining the reinforcement learning model\\ Documentation\end{tabular}}        \\ \cline{2-3}
                          & \multirow{June}   & Week1 &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            \\ \cline{3-3}
                          &                         & Week2 &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            \\ \cline{3-3}
                          &                         & Week3 &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            \\ \cline{3-4} 
                          &                         & Week4 & \multirow{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Literature studies on the shortest path planning and optimizing the energy consumption with reinforcement learning \\ Documentation\end{tabular}}                                               \\ \cline{2-3}
                          & \multirow{July}   & Week1 &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            \\ \cline{3-4} 
                          &                         & Week2 & \multirow{Reconstructing/Extending the reinforcement learning model to include the shortest path following}                                                                                                                          \\ \cline{3-3}
                          &                         & Week3 &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            \\ \cline{3-3}
                          &                         & Week4 &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            \\ \cline{2-4} 
                          & \multirow{August} & Week1 & \multirow{Documentation and Finalization}                                                                                                                                                                                            \\ \cline{3-3}
                          &                         & Week2 &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            \\ \cline{3-3}
                          &                         & Week3 &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            \\ \cline{3-3}
                          &                         & Week4 &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In your second table, all `\multirow` commands are missing their first and second argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution for the second table. If you want to group both tables, the paper size is too small in landscape, or you should  use `longtable` to splt it across pages.

You should understand that `multirow` does not work automagically, and that need to tell it the number of rows the contents will spread  over, and what width it requires. Using `*`  for the width makes it use the natural width of the contents. Other than that, I used the `\Shortunderstack` command from  `stackengine` to have a simpler code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[paperheight=11in,paperwidth=7in, margin=0.5in,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine} 
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \multirow{15}{*}{Roadmap} &\multirow{2}{*}{May} & \multirow{-2}{*}{Week2} & \makecell[l]{Inserting certain fixed object(s) to be considered as obstacle(s)\\ Reconstructing the reinforcement learning model\\ Retraining the reinforcement learning model\\ Documentation} \\[-2.8ex] \cline{3-3}
    & & Week3 & \\ \cline{3-4}
    & & Week4 & \smash{\Shortunderstack[l]{Transforming the obstacles from fixed to dynamic\\ Reconstructing/Extending the reinforcement learning model\\ Retraining the reinforcement learning model\\ Documentation}} \\ \cline{2-3}
    & \multirow{4}{*}{June} & Week1 & \\ \cline{3-3}
    & & Week2 & \\ \cline{3-3}
    & & Week3 & \\ \cline{3-4}
    & & Week4 & \smash{\Shortunderstack[l]{Literature studies on the shortest path planning and optimizing the energy consumption with reinforcement learning \\ Documentation}} \\ \cline{2-3}
    & \multirow{4}{*}{July} & Week1 & \\ \cline{3-4}
    & & Week2 & \\ cline{3-3}
    & & Week3 & Reconstructing/Extending the reinforcement learning model to include the shortest path following\\ \cline{3-3}
    & & Week4 & \\ \cline{2-4}
    & \multirow{4}{*}{August} & Week1 & \multirow{4}{*}{Documentation and Finalization} \\ \cline{3-3}
    & & Week2 & \\ \cline{3-3}
    & & Week3 & \\ \cline{3-3}
    & & Week4 & \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
   \end{table}

 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

And here solution with merged tables. Used are `xltabular` and `hhline` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=11in,paperwidth=7in, margin=0.5in,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{array, makecell, multirow}
\usepackage{xltabular}  % <--- new
%\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\linespread{0.96}\selectfont
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|l|l|l|X|}
    \hhline{|----|}
\multirow{40}{*}{Roadmap} 
    & \multirow{9}{*}{February} 
        & \multirow{2}{*}{Week 1}
            &   Installing the simulation environment \par
                Adding the UR manipulator to the simulation environment \par 
                Getting familiar with the simulation environment(learning how to include and position simple objects cube, ball, etc.)
    \\[-2.4ex]    \hhline{|~~-~|}
    &   & Week 2
    \\          \hhline{|~~--|}
    &   & \multirow{2}{*}{Week 3}
            &   Literature studies on grasping a cube and navigating between two waypoints\par
                Documentation
    \\          \hhline{|~~--|}
    &   & \multirow{5}{*}{Week 4}
        &   Literature studies on grasping a cube and navigating between (set of) waypoints\par
            Coding the navigation towards the position of the object\par
            Coding the grasp to the object\par
            Coding the navigation of the grasped object from it's initial position towards pre-defined target waypoint\par
            Documentation
    \\[-2.4ex]    \hhline{|~--~|}
    & \multirow{11}{*}{March}
        & Week 1
            &
    \\          \hhline{|~~-~|}
    \cline{3-4}
    &   & \multirow{-2}{*}{Week 2}
            & \makecell[l]{Literature studies on the cable implementation (reduced stiffness objects)\\
            Implementing and Positioning the cable at a certain position in the workspace\\ Documentation}
    \\[-2.4ex]      \hhline{|~~-~|}
    &   & Week 3 &
    \\              \hhline{|~~--|}
    &   & \multirow{-2}{*}{Week 4}
            & \makecell[l]{Coding the grasp to the cable and conducting the navigation from the initial to goal waypoint\\
            Confirming the no drop of the cable during the navigation\\
            Documentation \\
            ---\\
            \textit{Note: The items in this field are started to be applied in a fixed manner (No machine learning model to be developed). }\\
            \textit{In case the fixed manner isn't giving sufficient results, an RL model to be developed, the task to be extended more three weeks} \\\textit{and the shortest path planning task to be eliminated}}
    \\[-2.4ex]     \hhline{|~--~|}
    & \multirow{8}{*}{April}
        & Week 1 &
    \\              \hhline{|~~--|}
    &   & \multirow{-2}{*}{Week 2}
            & \makecell[l]{Literature studies on reinforcement learning\\ (Deep deterministic policy gradient and Deep Q-learning)\\ Documentation}
    \\[-2.4ex]      \hhline{|~~-~|}
    &   & Week 3 &
    \\              \hhline{|~~--|}
    &   & \multirow{3}{*}{Week 4}
                &   Developing a Reinforcement learning model to navigate the grasped cable to the predefined target waypoint\par
                    Documentation \par
                    ---\par
                    \textit{Note: For the grasping task, the code developed in the March's 4th week will be} used
    \\[-2.4ex]      \hhline{|~--~|}
    & \multirow{6}{*}{May}
        & Week 1 &
    \\              \hhline{|~~--|}%\hline
    &   & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{Week 2}
                & \multirow{2}{=}{%
                    Inserting certain fixed object(s) to be considered as obstacle(s)\newline
                    Reconstructing the reinforcement learning model\newline
                    Retraining the reinforcement learning model\newline
                    Documentation}     
    \\[2.4ex]              \hhline{|~~-~|}%\hline
    &   & \multirow{2}[2]{*}[0.5ex]{Week 3}
            &
    \\[2.8ex]              \hhline{|~~--|}%\hline
    &   & Week 4    &   \multirow{3}{=}{%
                    Transforming the obstacles from fixed to dynamic\newline
                    Reconstructing/Extending the reinforcement learning model\newline
                    Retraining the reinforcement learning model\newline
                    Documentation}
    \\          \hhline{|~--~|}
    & \multirow{4}{*}{June}
        & Week 1 &
    \\          \hhline{|~~-~|}
    &   & Week 2 &
    \\          \hhline{|~~-~|}
    &   & Week 3 &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            \\*          \hhline{|----|}
\multicolumn{4}{c}{}
   \\        \hhline{|----|}
\multirow{7}{*}{Roadmap}
    & June
        & Week 4    &                                             
    \\         \hhline{|~--~|}
    &   & Week 1 & \multirow{-2}{*}{%
                    Literature studies on the shortest path planning and optimizing the energy consumption with reinforcement learning \newline
                    Documentation} 
    \\*        \hhline{|~~--|}
    & \multirow{2}{*}{July}
        & Week 2 &   \multirow{3}{=}{%
                    Reconstructing/Extending the reinforcement learning model to include the shortest path following}
     \\        \hhline{|~~-~|}
    &   & Week 3 &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            \\        \hhline{|~~-~|}
    &   & Week4 &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            \\        \hhline{|~~-~|}
    & \multirow{4}{*}{August}
        & Week1 &   \multirow{4}{=}{Documentation and Finalization}                                                                                                                                                                                            \\        \hhline{|~~-~|}
    &   & Week2 &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            \\        \hhline{|~~-~|}
    &   & Week3 &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            \\        \hhline{|~~-~|}
    &   & Week4 &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            \\        \hhline{|~~-~|}
    \end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```